# Understanding Tibble error message when handling a MICE code

Tags: error-handling, tibble, r-mice

I'm running a MICE imputation following the instructions [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/finalfit/vignettes/missing.html). My question involves trying to understand what the error message is telling me and how I could go about correcting the Tibble error within the code below.

Thank you

```
full_dataset %>% 
  dplyr::filter(vector_x ==1) %>%
  dplyr::mutate_if(
     is.factor,
            fct_explicit_na,
            na_level="Missing"
  ) %>% 
  finalfit(dependent, explanatory) %>% 
    knitr::kable(row.names=FALSE, align = c("l", "l", "r", "r", "r", "r"))
```

Error:
! Tibble columns must have compatible sizes.

- Size 42: Existing data.
- Size 30: Column at position 5.
  i Only values of size one are recycled.
  Backtrace:

  1. ... %>% finalfit(dependent, explanatory)
  2. finalfit::finalfit(., dependent, explanatory)
  3. finalfit `<fn>`(...)
  4. finalfit:::fit2df.glm(...)
  5. finalfit:::extract_fit.glm(...)

10. dplyr::tibble(...)
11. tibble:::tibble_quos(xs, .rows, .name_repair)
12. tibble:::vectbl_recycle_rows(res, first_size, j, given_col_names[[j]])

Comment: Can you please edit the question to include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? This page might also be useful reading, https://finalfit.org/articles/missing.html

Comment: Thanks, David. That final fit page was referenced in the original question. I will try and include a reproducible example. But I don't understand the error. So, i am unlikely to achieve this,

Comment: Oh, I apologize about the redundant link. I must've lost track of my open tabs. Sorry. Perhaps the `mice::boys` dataset could be adapted as an example?

Comment: There is likely an error in your underlying model. Exchange the `finalfit` line for `summary_factorlist` and remove the `knitr` line. Does the table look as expected? Then change `summary_factorlist` to `glmmulti` - does your model run as expected?